# Symfony 5 Fast Track: Database access error

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I'm trying to go through the aforementioned tutorial, but I get stuck on the stage between Step 7 and 9 - when the database goes into action.
On local server I get

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

and while on my deployment server everything seems to work good when reading the database:
https://akodg6sfgq-gijxpyj6oxpig.eu.s5y.io/admin/
and entering the conference, when I enter a comment https://akodg6sfgq-gijxpyj6oxpig.eu.s5y.io/admin?crudAction=new&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CCommentCrudController&menuIndex=2&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fakodg6sfgq-gijxpyj6oxpig.eu.s5y.io%2Fadmin%3FcrudAction%3Dindex%26crudControllerFqcn%3DApp%255CController%255CAdmin%255CCommentCrudController%26menuIndex%3D2%26signature%3DGrbeBTskRKkJuU_MbS0do5B1M2XowgfTuOLaqpPQl4M%26submenuIndex%3D-1&signature=Rre3TFXH2NDeRLj9W-LKo6RJXR1fbvm37Cu8H04gfQM&submenuIndex=-1it hits me with

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

I don't know if these two are parts of the same problem, but it coincides.

My .env configuration:

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=c3aa1e6b44cb8d1cf26c5137433ed753
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

.symfony.cloud.yaml:

```
name: app

type: php:8.0

runtime:
    extensions:
        - apcu
        - mbstring
        - sodium
        - ctype
        - iconv
        - pdo_pgsql
        

#variables:
#    php:
#        # uncomment on PHP 7.4+
#        #opcache.preload: /app/config/preload.php

build:
    flavor: none

disk: 512

web:
    locations:
        "/":
            root: "public"
            expires: 1h
            passthru: "/index.php"



mounts:
    "/var": { source: local, source_path: var }

hooks:
    build: |
        set -x -e

        curl -fs https://get.symfony.com/cloud/configurator | (>&2 bash)
        
        (>&2 symfony-build)

    deploy: |
        set -x -e

        (>&2 symfony-deploy)

relationships:
    database: "db:postgresql"
```

services.yaml:

```
db:
    type: postgresql:13
    disk: 1024
    size: S
```

Docker-compose ps returns:

```
       Name                   Command           State            Ports         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
guestbook_database_1   docker-entrypoint.sh      Up      0.0.0.0:49153->5432/tcp
                       postgres                          ,:::49153->5432/tcp
```

and its configuration is:

```
version: '3'

services:
    database:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: main
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: main
            POSTGRES_DB: main
        ports: [5432]
```

Any ideas? It started after entering API endpoints in the controllers. Basically any access to database. I don't want to go further until I resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps just a bit of too much information but it appears that your DATABASE_URL is missing the user name and password which seems consistent with the initial error message.  The format should be: DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"  But following tutorials without understanding what is going on can be very tricky.  One tiny error someplace and everything can blow up.

Comment: I tried adding main:main@127.0.0.1/main?... and then I got:
```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "main"
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "main"
```

Comment: Also, the above construct is suggested explicitly here: 
"Why does the information need to be duplicated in two different places? Because on some Cloud platforms, at build time, the database URL might not be known yet but Doctrine needs to know the database’s engine to build its configuration. So, the host, username, and password do not really matter."
https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/8-doctrine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you - the username and password were correct. it appears the database has given me the wrong port info. I've run the "symfony run psql" and \conninfo and got the proper port